# Understand how to squash commits

Tags: git, github

So, a diff between  `master` and my branch (`foo`) showed 3 files changed on github.

Now, on my local branch `foo`, I did `git reset --soft <commit_hash>` to squash commits, added and committed it, then force pushed it to `origin foo`

The diff now says there are 10 files changed!? How is this possible?

As I see it, all I've done is squashed my commits; I haven't changed `master`. I was expecting the diff to be the same as it was before squashing.

Comment: In `git reset --soft head <commit>`, what's `<commit>`? Also, this should have given you an error saying that you "_cannot do soft reset with paths_".

Comment: Edited to reflect I meant commit hash

Comment: How did you push your branch?  Note that it would have required a force push, assuming you really did squash.  If you _didn't_ force push, then it is likely you did not squash.  What is `head` doing in your soft reset command?

Comment: @nz_21 I meant which commit did you reset to? The one before your latest one? Three commits ago? Also, that command should have given you an error, did it not?

Comment: @Tim whoops, sorry! Yup, I've traced back my exact commands edited the question details

Comment: You didn't really answer my questions, but unless you changed the files after you squashed, then in general what you are seeing can't happen.

Comment: Did you see also that the difference between `master` and `foo` locally is 3 files before the squash?

Comment: Also, abstracting ourselves from the 10 file changes, are the changes in your newly squashed commit the ones you want and are the diffs (regardless of the numbers of file changes) the ones you expect?

Comment: Did you added with `git add .` ?

Answer (score 3):

There's not really a way for us to diagnose this after-the-fact.  I'll talk through the assumptions that would make your procedure work as expected, and maybe this will help find if anything went wrong.  Also I will recommend that for squashing commits, it's better to use `rebase -i`.  Yes, there's a small extra step of editing the todo list, but it more explicitly tells git what you mean to do, so mistakes are less likely.

So...

Assuming you `reset` to the correct commit (the merge base between `foo` and `master`), and that your worktree and index where clean when you started (i.e. everything had been staged and committed and nothing changed afterward), *and* `master` didn't receive new commits in the mean time (you said you're diffing `foo` against `master`, but probably should be diffing `foo` against the merge base of `foo` and `master`) the diff shouldn't change.

That is, if you started with something like

```
x -- x -- O <--(master)
           \
            A -- B -- C <--(foo)
```

then *just squashing the commits* means you should end with

```
x -- x -- O <--(master)
           \
            ABC <--(foo)
```

The content at `ABC` should match the content you had at `C`, and `O` is of course unchanged, so the diff should be the same.

But let's look at each assumption:

**reset to the correct commit**

In general, you could actually have started with something like

```
x -- x -- O -- y <--(master)
           \
            A -- B -- C <--(foo)
```

You would still want to make your replacement commit *from `O`, and not from the current `master` head*., or else your "squashed" commit would implicitly undo the changes from `y`.  That is you want to end with

```
x -- x -- O -- y <--(master)
           \
            ABC <--(foo)
```

and not

```
x -- x -- O -- y <--(master)
                \
                 ~yABC <--(foo)
```

(If you instead want to end with

```
x -- x -- O -- y <--(master)
                \
                 ABC <--(foo)
```

then you *really* need to be looking at a `rebase` instead of a `reset`.)

So the reset command could be something like

```
git reset --soft $(git merge-base master foo)
```

or if you know how many commits are on the branch

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

or if you know the specific has for `O` already, you can just use that.

**worktree and index clean**

A soft reset leaves the worktree and index unchanged while moving `HEAD`.  This means that even uncommitted and unstaged changes (and untracked files) are still there.  So when you `add` and `commit`, you may include things that weren't previously committed.  To start this type of squash, you would

```
git checkout foo
git status
```

and make sure `status` says that the worktree is clean and there is nothing to commit.

**`master` didn't change**

If you're using `git` as intended and didn't do anything that would change `master` (such as `pull` changes from a remote), then this shouldn't be an issue.  But just to cover all bases, if you're diffing against `master` (instead of against the merge base) then you're also seeing changes between `O` and `master` - so if `master` changes in the interim (such that you end up with

```
x -- x -- O -- y -- z <--(master)
           \
            ABC <--(foo)
```

...) then your diff result will change.